# Can a .net project discover and use a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, .net-2.0, wcf-binding

I have created a basic WCF service in IIS. I am aware that this should be developed in .net 3.0 and .net 3.5. My question is this. Can a client running .net 2.0 access and consume the WCF service?

Cheers

Comment: I don't see why you can't. Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Comment: I came across this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/eb87043a-3e4f-4c43-9577-8173b5ed80ae/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the service exposes an endoint with [basicHttpBinding](http://basicHttpBinding). Although there are some [*issues*](http://blogs.msdn.com/eugeneos/archive/2007/02/05/solving-the-disappearing-data-issue-when-using-add-web-reference-or-wsdl-exe-with-wcf-services.aspx) you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

as darin said you can access the service from 2.0 only if your wcf is exposed using the basicHttpBinding. This binding will expose SOAP that is compatible with **WS-BasicProfile 1.1** which is the same as the older ASMX services.